# Form a list y of records out of the list z of records; the element(record) of list y is member of element(record) of list z

Tags: erlang

I am quite new to erlang and trying to achieve following:

```
Y  = lists:map(fun(#l1_dl_se{l1_dl_se_common = Y#l1_dl_se_common}) -> Y end,Z)
```

where Z is a list of records of type l1_dl_se. 
I am trying to get list y of records of type l1_dl_se_common from the list Z. Where l1_dl_se_common is a member of record l1_dl_se.
I am getting compilation error. Are there any alternative ways to achieve above?

Comment: Incidentally, if you're learning erlang, I can't recommend http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content enough. It's an invaluable and informative guide to learn from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for matching Y is off.  Try:

```
Y = lists:map(fun(#l1_dl_se{l1_dl_se_common = #l1_dl_se_common{} =Y}) -> Y end,Z)
```

Also, all variables must start with a capital letter, so `z` cannot be a list, and `y` won't match your output.